# PHP REST Authentication token for Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: php, azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building a PHP based webpage. I want to use REST APIs to store, read and update data in an AZURE Cosmos DB.
First challenge is to generate the authentication token with the masterkey. I used the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources
and a postman collection* as a reference to build the code below.

*see
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ndj_-zp82Y
https://github.com/MicrosoftCSA/documentdb-postman-collection

I used the console log from postman to compare each step and figured out that there are different results** but I have no clue how to get the same results from my PHP like from Postman

**
key64 PHP:
WUtDMFF5VWZkZ1NsTFp5UmU5ZVBMbW9jV3ZSN.....==
key64 Postman:
60a0b443251f7604a52d9c917bd78f2e6a1c5af4790d3f67dc7dbd513d173418... NO == at the end
authstring PHP:
type%253Dmaster%2526ver%253D1.0%2526sig%.....
authstring POSTMAN:
type%3Dmaster%26ver%3D1.0%26sig%3.....

```
POSTMAN (JS)
// store our master key for documentdb
var mastKey = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("DocumentDBMasterKey");
console.log("mastKey = " + mastKey);

// store our date as RFC1123 format for the request
var today = new Date();
var UTCstring = today.toUTCString();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("RFC1123time", UTCstring);

// Grab the request url
var url = request.url.trim(); 
console.log("request url = " + url);

// strip the url of the hostname up and leading slash
var strippedurl = url.replace(new RegExp('^https?://[^/]+/'),'/');
console.log ("stripped Url = " + strippedurl);

// push the parts down into an array so we can determine if the call is on a specific item
// or if it is on a resource (odd would mean a resource, even would mean an item)
var strippedparts = strippedurl.split("/");
var truestrippedcount = (strippedparts.length - 1);
console.log(truestrippedcount);

// define resourceId/Type now so we can assign based on the amount of levels
var resourceId = "";
var resType = "";

// its odd (resource request)
if (truestrippedcount % 2)
{
    console.log("odd");
    // assign resource type to the last part we found.
    resType = strippedparts[truestrippedcount];
    console.log("resType");
    console.log(resType);
    if (truestrippedcount > 1)
    {
        // now pull out the resource id by searching for the last slash and substringing to it.
        var lastPart = strippedurl.lastIndexOf("/");
        resourceId = strippedurl.substring(1,lastPart);
        console.log(resourceId);
    }
}
else // its even (item request on resource)
{
    console.log("even");
    // assign resource type to the part before the last we found (last is resource id)
    resType = strippedparts[truestrippedcount - 1];
    console.log("resType");
    // finally remove the leading slash which we used to find the resource if it was
    // only one level deep.
    strippedurl = strippedurl.substring(1);
    console.log("strippedurl");
    // assign our resourceId
    resourceId = strippedurl;
    console.log("resourceId");
    console.log(resourceId);
}

// assign our verb
var verb = request.method.toLowerCase();

// assign our RFC 1123 date
var date = UTCstring.toLowerCase();

// parse our master key out as base64 encoding
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(mastKey);
console.log("key = " + key);

// build up the request text for the signature so can sign it along with the key
var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
               (resType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
               (resourceId || "") + "\n" + 
               (date || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
               "" + "\n";
console.log("text = " + text);

// create the signature from build up request text
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text, key);
console.log("sig = " + signature);

// back to base 64 bits
var base64Bits = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);
console.log("base64bits = " + base64Bits);

// format our authentication token and URI encode it.
var MasterToken = "master";
var TokenVersion = "1.0";
auth = encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + base64Bits);
console.log("auth = " + auth);

// set our auth token enviornmental variable.
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("authToken", auth);
```

PHP CODE

```
#PHP Script
function generateAuthKey($url, $method){
$key = "****************";
    $date = new DateTime('');
    $date = $date->format('D, d M Y H:i:s O');
    $ressourcetype = "";
    $strippedurl = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $strippedparts = explode("/", $strippedurl);
    $strippedurlcount = sizeof($strippedparts)-1;

    #GET RESSOURCE TYPE
    if ($strippedurlcount % 2){
        $resType = $strippedparts[$strippedurlcount];
    
        if ($strippedurlcount > 1){
            $ressourcetype = $strippedparts[$strippedurlcount];
        }
    }
    else{
       $ressourcetype = $strippedparts[$strippedurlcount-1];
    }
    $sig = nl2br(strtolower($method)."\n".strtolower($ressourcetype)."\n".$strippedurl."\n".strtolower($date)."\n".""."\n");
    $sig = utf8_encode($sig);
    $key64 = base64_encode($key);
    echo $key64."\n";
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256',$sig,$key64);

    $token = "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=".$hmac;
    return urlencode($token);
}
```

How can I change the PHP script to provide the same output as Postman (JS)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the following line of code:

```
$key64 = base64_encode($key);
```

As per the [`REST API documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources#constructkeytoken), you should be doing a [`base64_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) of your key as the key is already base64 encoded.

Please try by changing your code to:

```
$key64 = base64_decode($key);
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav,
thanks for your reply - I tested your suggestion but now the result looks like windings:

`��C%v�-��{׏.jZ�y ?g�}�....

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge in PHP is somewhat limited. Can you try something for me please? Don't decode/encode the key and simply use it as is in your `hash_hmac` function. Something like: `$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256',$sig,$key);`

Comment: You may need to convert the output of that function into base64.

Comment: the output of 
 $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256',$sig,$key);
 $hmac = base64_encode($hmac); is
M2E1ODliMjcxZjFjZDQ0M2ExNzczZjhiYjc4NjYyOTFhNDI0ZDg4...

while the output in the Postman console is
key = 60a0b443251f7604a52d9c917bd78f2e6a1c5af4790d3f67dc7

Comment: This values would be different because of the different date/time values you use in Postman and in your code. Try with a hardcoded date/time value and see if you get the same result.

Comment: the key does not use date and time key is just hashed and in postman it 's always the same key (also PHP but the key is different)

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, I'll note a couple issues with the author's code:

- It was not necessary to `utf8_encode()` -- trying to utf8 encode a string that is already valid ISO-8859-1 can produce unexpected results. Also note that this method is deprecated as of PHP 8.2.0.
- The author was returning the string output of `hash_hmac()`, rather than binary.

Here is how you correctly generate a signature in PHP. Bear in mind that all requests to the Cosmos REST API, needs to include an `x-ms-date` header, which matches the same date used to generate the token. It's up to you how to want to handle that, but in my case, I chose to return the date and token as an array from the function. You could also consider making the function return the entire header array all at once.

I am using Carbon and Guzzle in this example.

```php
private function cosmosAuth(string $method, string $resourceType, string $resourceLink)
{
    $date = Carbon::now()->toRfc7231String();
    // alternatively:   gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T')

    $key = base64_decode(MY_COSMOS_KEY);

    $body = $method . "\n" .
        $resourceType . "\n" .
        $resourceLink . "\n" .
        $date . "\n" .
        "\n";

    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', strtolower($body), $key, true);
    $signature = base64_encode($hash);

    $tokenType = "master";
    $tokenVersion = "1.0";
    $token = urlencode("type={$tokenType}&ver={$tokenVersion}&sig={$signature}");

    return [
        'date' => $date,
        'token' => $token
    ];
}
```

Here is an example of a request to update a document. Note if you created your collection with a partition key, you also must pass the partition key **value** in the `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` header. The format here is a little janky, with Microsoft expecting a string representation of an array containing the value.

```
$resource = "dbs/{$database}/colls/{$collection}/docs/{$documentId}";
$auth = $this->cosmosAuth("PUT", "docs", $resource);

try {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $client->request("PUT", "https://{$account}.documents.azure.com/{$resource}", [
        'headers' => [
            'authorization' => $auth['token'],
            'x-ms-date' => $auth['date'],
            'x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey' => '["'.$documentId.'"]',
        ],
        'json' => $documentData
    ]);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->log("error: {$e->getMessage()}");
}
```

Microsoft resources:

- [Constructing a hashed token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources#constructkeytoken)
- [Replace a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/replace-a-document)